# Magento 2 how to override theme-adminhtml-backend view.xml in custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, overrides, product-images

By default Magento 2 creates more than 20 duplicates of each product image..! (why???)

I have got this down to 5 using view.xml in my theme, but there is one extra set of image sizes I need to change, these are set in

`/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/etc/view.xml`.

```
They are: product_listing_thumbnail, product_listing_thumbnail_preview, product_thumbnail_image.
```

I want to update it using my custom module. I have it at this path

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/etc/view.xml`.

But this is wrong. Is there a correct path that will work? (If creating an admin theme is the only way then I guess I could do that, but seems overkill for just one small change).

(Have spent ages looking online and through docs but can only find info for frontend view.xml, which I am already using, and putting the image names in this file does not work).

Many Thanks!

Comment: This cannot be done using a custom module as the file is theme specific. if you update your theme etc/view.xml and include the additional elements this should create the additional required images you need

Comment: @DavaGordon Yes I think you are correct it cannot be done from a custom module as it is a 'theme file'. So it must be done by creating a new custom admin theme. If you post as an answer I will accept  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using a custom module as the file is theme specific. if you update your theme etc/view.xml and include the additional elements this should create the additional required images you need

Comment: Note: I do also have to create a custom module to set the admin theme. ( ...a whole module required just to do that...!!? ):/

Answer (score 1):

please try:-

override view.xml in your theme

> path:- app/design/adminhtml/Vander/your-them/etc/view.xml

Comment: Is there a way to override this in /app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/ ?

Comment: please try. override view.xml /app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/etc/view.xml

Comment: Hmm no sorry that path didn't work :(,  the images are still being resized to 75x75 as set in '/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/etc/view.xml'. (after adding view.xml to new path I did setup:upgrade, cache clean, manually cleared product image cache, and ran catalog:images:resize)